# DataSet Serialization Problem in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, dataset, data-integrity

I have a dataset containing several tables, which is populated from a stored procedure. I want to make it nested for the GetXml() method.

I added the relation:

```
set.Relations.Add(
    new DataRelation("Author_Document",
        new DataColumn[] { set.Tables["Author"].Columns["lngDocumentSeriesId"], set.Tables["Author"].Columns["strAuthorName"] },
        new DataColumn[] { set.Tables["Document"].Columns["lngDocumentSeriesId"], set.Tables["Document"].Columns["strAuthorName"] }, true));
```

I made it nested:

```
foreach (DataRelation relation in set.Relations)
{
    relation.Nested = true;
}
```

And enforced:

```
set.EnforceConstraints = true;
```

All of which run fine, with no errors. The problem is when I call `set.GetXml()`, which throws a DataException: "*Cannot proceed with serializing DataTable 'Document'. It contains a DataRow which has multiple parent rows on the same Foreign Key*".

Upon inspection, the tables in question have each just a single row. The columns lngDocumentSeriesId and strAuthorName match. Even if there were a data integrety problem, it should have caused the exception on the `set.EnforceConstraints = true;` line, as I understand it.

What could cause this error (when all tables have just a single row), and how can it be fixed?

Comment: when you set `Nested` to `false` , does `GetXml()` work as expected?

Comment: Menahem: Yes it does. Each table has a single row represented (not nested, obviously), and the columns in the foreign key match.

Comment: any other relations on the dataset ?

Comment: There are, but if I comment out the one in question it works OK. Ahhhhh....just worked it out! You're right...there are two different tables that are each the parent, and each has one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

any other relations on the dataset ? ('there are two different tables that are each the parent, and each has one row')